# How is it possible this accepted answer got deleted?

Tags: support, answers, deleted-answers, accepted-answer

As we all know when an answer is accepted the author can't delete it themselves. It can be deleted by moderators, but the answer gets unaccepted during the deletion.

How is it possible [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3127352) is still accepted despite being deleted?

[image]

Comment: *but the answer gets unaccepted during the deletion* - it doesn't actually technically get unaccepted in the same sense as if the question asker actually unaccepted the answer  - what happens is that the check mark isn't shown and it's no longer considered in reputation calculations (but should it be undeleted, it gets shown again and counts towards reputation again)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Before late 2012, under special circumstances, deleted accepted answers retained the checkmark. The reasons are not entirely clear. Undeleting and deleting solves the issue.

---

It seems that about [since October 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328219/what-happens-to-the-accepted-answer-when-a-question-is-deleted#comment1071615_328220) the checkmark has always been removed (see also the [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/328220) that comment was posted to), but not before.

In February 2011, [Grace Note](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79582) wrote that the checkmark was typically deleted also and:

> Even if the acceptance mark is visible on the deleted answer (which I guess is the case for a flag deletion, given your >10k status and tone of question),...

In March 2012 a [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125984) claimed:

> If, on the other hand, only the accepted answer is deleted, it retains the checkmark.

[Shog9](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148507) wrote about an answer deleted in 2011:

> It appears there was a time when deleting an answer didn't remove that checkmark - and this answer was deleted then.

But what deleted it, [he has](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148502/deleted-accepted-answer-pinned-as-top-answer#comment426871_148507)

> No idea. Lost in the mists of time, no doubt.

Comment: So, it retains the vote, but not the characteristics of the vote.