# Why does the UI still show "Accepted" icon for an "Accepted" answer which has been deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, accepted-answer

This question is focussed on a specific problem that I found after executing the query, https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1373777/meta-stackoverflow-com-questions-405196

This query lists the links to the accepted answer of deleted questions for which I had written an answer.

**Note:** Please check [this helpful answer by rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/405201/10819573) in order to understand how to create this query.

The problem I see is that one of the 61 links in the result points to an answer which still shows the "Accepted" icon:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64188879/i-want-to-change-the-string-of-letters-xxx-xxx-xxxx-into-333-333-3333-i-tried-th/64188996#64188996

As far as I have understood, if an "Accepted" answer gets deleted, the UI does not show its "Accepted" icon. What is different for this particular answer?

The duplicate target, [How is it possible this accepted answer got deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400740/how-is-it-possible-this-accepted-answer-got-deleted) does not answer this question. The answer in that question talks about pre-Oct2012 feature but the answer I am talking about was posted in Oct2020.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is it possible this accepted answer got deleted?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400740/how-is-it-possible-this-accepted-answer-got-deleted)

Comment: Jeanne Dark - No. Thanks for posting this link. However, the answer I am talking about was posted just 4 months ago whereas the answer in your links talks about 2012.

Comment: a possible difference is that the question still has a valid user. On your other example the user was nuked, either by the mod that handled the plagiarism flag or the user themselves decided to delete their account. That event probably updated the question but didn't remove all votes from that user, at least not the accept vote. It is a glitch in the universe. Don't worry about it.

Comment: rene - Thanks again for the nice comment, `It is a glitch in the universe` . In the list, there are 16 other answers whose users are still valid but the Accepted icon is absent as expected. Only this particular answer is different.

Comment: *Only this particular answer is different.* --> that's the definition of a *glitch* otherwise it would be a *feature*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've raised bugs about data inconsistencies before, for example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141101/) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301543) and those were on non-deleted posts.

What exactly happens during deletion and in which state the data in Posts and Votes should be is undefined. IIRC correctly not everything runs inside a transaction and if two actions take place within seconds it is not uncommon those actions act on stale data.

It is a waste of time and effort to find the root cause, lose sleep over it or have a developer dig through the logs which race conditions was applicable here.

Just be happy you got somewhat useful data out of some whacky query. Can we please move on now?